# Azure Active Directory B2C with react native

Tags: javascript, azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I did this [azure ad b2c web api tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet) that get's an authorization token with postman and sends it to the API. But how do I get an authorization token from a react native app? When I create the application, do I choose 'Web App / Web API' or 'Native client'? And is there any examples / resources that I can use? Can I use this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-hellojs-singlepageapp) with [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)?
Im confused because react native is built with JS but compiled to native code.

Comment: When you have the question of Web app / API or native, you need to ask this question from yourself: Does this app run on the user's device? If the answer is yes, then the app is native.

Comment: A React Native app is native.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem - did you find any solution?

Comment: no i didn't. :/

Comment: Hey @thatsIT check this and let me know if it works for you:
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad

Comment: Thanks @AndresElizondo but Im not working on that anymore.

Comment: I am working on this now. I will post up if I find anything.

Comment: MSAL for JS can not be used for React Native apps due to its underlying storage dependencies. See Github Issue https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/825

Answer (score 2):

Check https://github.com/GSingh01/ad-b2c-react-native. It uses latest spec from Microsoft and JS based solution thus you don't need to eject from expo.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you plan to use the login from you RN App to both validate the user is valid and to then request data over Azure hosted API endpoints, you should setup your AD B2C Application to allow both Web\Web API AND Native Client.

<s>If you are OK with using the web-based login from your App which jumps out to the mobile browser and then back to your app, have a look at [Visual Studio App Center Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/auth/react-native).</s>

NOTE: App Center Auth has been retired: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/app-center-mbaas-retirement/

If you wish to use your own screens hosted in your RN App, you then will need to follow a JWT authentication example. Details of that would be a separate question though.